# iOS - How To Test iPhone Hardware Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to get device information and to test how well the phone is working overall?  It seems like you can get some info about the device with the UIDevice class.  My main question is if there is a way to test how well the phone is working.  For example, is the battery good or does it die in an hour?  Is the CPU working well or is the phone going to lag more?  Any tips on how I can achieve this from within the app itself(when not connected to computer)?  I want the user to be able to figure out how well their phone is working.  If I can get the battery percent, maybe I can tell how fast it depletes while doing background actions or something along those lines.  Anyway, thanks for any information!

Comment: I'm sure you could find answers to this if you researched it on google (or bing or netscape)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html)

https://www.universalmind.com/blog/what-every-ios-developer-should-be-doing-with-instruments/

Comment: That seems useful but I don't believe it is what I am looking for.  I want something where the user can test the phone within the app.  That seems to be just a profiling tool for debugging.  Thank you though, I may use that for the app either way!